# can we use 2 " 's" in a sentence like this?

Tags: grammar, punctuation

I wonder if this sentence is rightly or wrongly punctuated : 'It's "How I Met Your Mother" 's time'.

Comment: Think not so much about whether it's right or wrong as about the likely reception by the reader.

Comment: yes but i'm learning English and i want to know that it's ok or not so i can fix it :) Thanks for your comment ^^

Comment: While I demonstrated in my answer the proper way to make mother possessive, it would be much more common to say, [Don't bother me], *it's "How I Met Your Mother" time.* The possessive is not required. That simply means *It's time for "How I Met Your Mother."*

Answer (score 3):

If you mean to say that you do not want to be disturbed while watching *How I met your mother,* then the apostrophe and *s* need to be inside the quotes.

> "It's *How I Met Your Mother*'s time".

If you're asking if you can use *it's* and *mother's* in the same sentence, then the answer is yes.

For one, *it's* is a contraction of *it is,* not a possessive as *mother's* is. And even if it were, you can use two possessives in the same sentence, but double possessives are frowned upon.

For example, you could say, *Jennifer's car broke down on the way to Alice's house.*

It would be frowned upon to say, *Jennifer's car's engine blew up on the way to Alice's neighbor's house.*

While it's not technically wrong, it's awkward. It would be better said as, *The engine in Jennifer's car blew up on her way to meet Alice's neighbor.*

Comment: Awkward, but sometimes necessary. “Jennifer is Alice’s neighbour’s sister’s brother-in-law’s hairdresser”, for example, is hard to rephrase without at least two possessives in a row.

Comment: Agreed. I had hard time trying to think of a double possessive on the spot that would be completely unacceptable. I figured the best way to explain it to a non-native speaker would be to state that it should be avoided whenever possible, especially since it's  discouraged.

Comment: @Janus - _You know that lady who lives next to Alice? She has a sister who has a brother-in-law, and that guy gets his hair done by Jennifer, down at Indira's Salon._ In other words, you're correct :^) that was a lot of work to rephrase.